# Swift game crash OpenGL.h

Tags: swift, macos, opengl-es, sprite-kit, tvos

I am working on a test project, making a game for Apple tvOS. I have few sprites represented as circles, which leave a path when they move. Game is working ok for some time, but soon this error occours:

```
Assertion failed: (length + offset <= _length), function commit_data, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Jet_Sim/Jet-1.50/Jet/jet_types_OpenGL.h, line 863.
```

I am creating sprites like this:

```
sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:colorName)
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, sprite.position.x, sprite.position.y)
lineNode.path = path;
```

I am creating sprites path by moving them by 1 point in every update() function call and also logging their path like this

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(player.path, nil, player.sprite.position.x, player.sprite.position.y)
CGPathMoveToPoint(player.path, nil, player.sprite.position.x, player.sprite.position.y))
player.lineNode.path = player.path;
```

This occurs in simulator and also as OSX app build, that I tried just to test if there is the same problem. Hope someone can help.

**UPDATE**

I also noticed, if I don't add line path to view, it doesn't crash. No idea what is wrong.

```
//self.addChild(player.lineNode)
self.addChild(player.sprite)
```

Comment: Check your memory consumption. This is most likely a leak.

Comment: @MaticOblak running in xcode simulator, memory usage doesn't go above 100MB, also checking for leaks couldn't find anything. On apple tv game starts drawing some strange stripes over whole screen, right before crash.

Comment: Are you adding too many children then? A bit more info on what and how are you doing might be needed.

Comment: @MaticOblak This is multiplayer game snakes, when player joins these two rows are executed (as you can see under update in my post). These are only children I am adding (well I have 2 more for menu). There are no other children on my view. On update I am changing their position add drawing path with CGPath (again, code is visible in my post above). If I don't add players line to view, everything works fine. If I do add, game crashes after some time. There any other way I could draw path where child was moving?

Comment: I see there are only 2 lines but if this is executed on every frame that would make 120 children per second... The assertion that reports a fail suggest somewhere in the code there is a line assert(length+offset <= _length) (not your code). It would make sense this is some sort of a container where you may add items such as addChild. Most likely _length is the current size of the container as for instance CGPoint buffer[_length]. So the function wants to add another item at "length" which is out of bounds. Can you try and display the number of children before adding another?

Comment: This is code that executes only when player joins, it's not in update method. So there are max 10 nodes (4 for players, other for text on screen). I will make sure everything is ok with coordinates. Tnx for now, will report later!